# CCParallax for a moving background

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I got a tiled map and I want to make lava lakes. I wish to have some kind of lava texture image on the background looping diagonally slowly. I could make it with four 960x640 images and move all of them diagonally etc. But when I do, a black/white line appears between each...

... and someone suggested me "CCParallax". I have never used it and am not sure if it really can achieve the effect I am seeking.

Also note that as the player moves on the map, the parallax will need to simulate that as well etc.

So my question is, what would you do for this effect? Four looping images or "CCParallax"?

Answer (score 1):

CCParallaxNode is pretty limited because you can't specify endless parallax scrolling without modifying the class. It also doesn't quite fit your use case.

Using four 960x640 images is wasteful. Just to make some lakes underneath the background this is overkill and will negatively affect performance.

The solution depends a bit on how big the lakes are. For example, if these are just 1 or 3x3 tiles in size you could add a textured sprite underneath each lake. If on the other hand your tilemap consists mostly of a few narrow pathways while the rest is lava lakes, then you need a different approach.

You might want to [try GL_REPEAT](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/knowledge-base/cocos2d-iphone-faq/learn-cocos2d-public-content/manual/cocos2d-general/14538-how-to-draw-an-endlessly-repeating-parallax-background/) to repeat a single sprite's texture over a defined area. That allows you to use a relatively small texture, for example 64x64, that will be repeated over the rectangle you specified.

You can then modify the sprite's position each frame to scroll the texture. Every time the sprite has moved 64 pixels in horizontal or vertical direction, you subtract 64 pixels (sprite.contentSize.width) from the sprite's position to reset it back to its original state. That means the sprite will never move further than 64 pixels from its initial position in any direction but you still get smooth scrolling.

Comment: If I had animated tiles for the lava lakes, do you think it would be better? Because recently I manage to animate my tiles (their texture rect coordinates update every X frames etc)... Thank you by the way. I will try these out.

Comment: I have tested your GL_REPEAT method with a 960x640 (retina) image. There seems to be a certain empty space between each image (around 40 points). Why is that?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention, with GL_REPEAT the texture *must* be a power of two. So you have to use 256x32 or 1024x1024 or any other power of two sizes to make the blank areas go away.

Comment: Will that also fix the bad quality thing? I will give it a go ~

Comment: Hmm, I believe that the spacing problem is over, but for some reason, my image is still pixelated/bad quality D: